# Angular toggle not working after submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, toggle

I am playing around with Angular and came about an issue. The toggle I have set up on the Edit button works until I either click on the Save or Cancel button. Then it doesn't work anymore.

Here is my Plunker: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/Vy2WeUkk7jvIjp1z8Sfi

```
<section ng-controller="ContactController">
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
        <h3>
            {{ contact.id }}
            <em class="pull-right">{{contact.fname }} {{ contact.lname }} <button ng-click="editing = !editing">Edit</button></em>
            <form ng-show="editing" ng-submit="editing = false" ng-controller="FormController">
                <input type="hidden" ng-model="contact.id">
                <label>First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="contact.fname" placeholder="first name" ng-required/>
                <label>Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="contact.lname" placeholder="last name" ng-required/>
                <br/>
                <button class="btn" ng-click="Save();" type="submit">Save</button>
                <button class="btn" ng-click="editing = false">Cancel</button>
              </form>
        </h3>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </section>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ng-repeat` directive creates a new scope for contact element it iterates. Let's call this the contact scope. Because the Edit button is within the contact scope, clicking it will create an `editing` property on the contact scope.

When you use the `ng-controller` directive to create a `FormController`, you are creating a child scope, let's call it the form scope, whose prototype is the contact scope. This is why you can access properties from a parent scope directly from a child scope, and why the `ng-show` directive initially works in your code.

However, when you click the Cancel button, you are setting the `editing` property to `false` directly on the form scope and this overrides the value of `editing` on the contact scope. Since you are referencing `editing` on the form scope in your `ng-show` directive it is never going to show again since the Edit button modifies `editing` on the contact scope.

The way to fix this is to use the scope's `$parent` property whenever you are referencing editing in the form scope. This ensures you are watching and modifying `editing` on the contact scope.

```
<section ng-controller="ContactController">
<ul class="list-group">
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
    <h3>
        {{ contact.id }}
        <em class="pull-right">{{contact.fname }} {{ contact.lname }} <button ng-click="editing = !editing">Edit</button></em>
        <form ng-show="$parent.editing" ng-submit="$parent.editing = false" ng-controller="FormController">
            <input type="hidden" ng-model="contact.id">
            <label>First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="contact.fname" placeholder="first name" ng-required/>
            <label>Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="contact.lname" placeholder="last name" ng-required/>
            <br/>
            <button class="btn" ng-click="Save();" type="submit">Save</button>
            <button class="btn" ng-click="$parent.editing = false">Cancel</button>
        </form>
    </h3>
</li>
</ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and the code. That worked! I'm new to Angular so still learning but appreciate your help.
Any reason why my post was voted down?

Comment: A more experienced user may be able to better clarify, but my best guess is that the question was down voted because your plunk did not initially run the way you explained it. I had to make a number of unrelated changes to get it to a running state. Make sure your example code behaves exactly how you have explained in your questions.